# How can I distinguish between multiple instances of the same fragment in Android navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I've created a navigation graph that includes a fragment that includes an action to navigate to another instance of itself for the purposes of setting up a multiple choice question survey like this:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/multipleChoiceFragment"
        android:name="com.example.MultipleChoiceFragment"
        android:label="MultipleChoiceFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_multiple_choice_question">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_multipleChoiceFragment_to_multipleChoiceFragment"
            app:destination="@id/multipleChoiceFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="questionId"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="false" />
    </fragment>
```

and I have a parent fragment implementation, `SurveyFragment`, that is responsible for navigating through the instances of `MultipleChoiceFragment` via the `NavController` and setting different `questionId` values for each `MultipleChoiceFragment` depending on the answers given to previous `MultipleChoiceFragment` instances.

I can't seem to find a way to have the parent fragment, `SurveyFragment`, tell which `MultipleChoiceFragment` instance is currently visible. I am using a single ViewModel for all instances of `MultipleChoiceFragment` and `SurveyFragment`, but if I can I'd like all the navigation logic to be contained entirely within `SurveyFragment` and not split between all the different classes. I'd like to be able to use the `questionId` value to distinguish between instances. How can I do that?

I'd like to have something setup in the `SurveyFragment` that looks something like this:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.questionId) {
                // do stuff depending on what question has been navigated to
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your listener is also given the `arguments`. Is there a reason you aren't using that information?

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that... That answers the question. Thanks!

Comment: @ianhanniballake Do you know if there's a way to get that argument outside of the context of that listener? Do something like `navController.currentDestination.argumentBundle`? `navController.currentDestination.arguments` seems to be something different

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for `navController.currentBackStackEntry.arguments`?

Comment: Yep! That'll do. Thanks!